# How to use proguard on intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, proguard

I am using Intellij IDEA to develop java desktop application. And I want to obfuscate my source code using proguard. How to integrate/use proguard on Intellij IDEA 2016.1.14?

Comment: Add the Maven or Gradle plugin and away you go. To be honest though, the only advantage of Proguard is that it makes the code drop smaller - it deletes unused stuff. Forget any advantages that obfuscation gives you - any half competent developer can decompile and analyse obfuscated Java code. I would look at [Graal AOT images](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/295) for the size/startup performance and forget about obfuscation.

Comment: @Yonatan I recomend that you continue your search if not successful. I have decompiled jars, and my analysis is that, a person would have to be good enough to write the code themselves in order to make any use out of the decompilation. This in itself, is why nobody would decompile the code who could actually make use of anything within the code. It is difficult to implement obfuscation, but its 10 times harder to reverse engineer. I challenge everybody who reads this to prove me wrong. Drop yer links here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried this (i like to find the easy way first) but, it should work if you follow the steps. I will try this and report back.

1. Go to this link and learn how to create an [Ant build file for IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-ant-build-file.html)
2. Go here to download [yGuard](http://www.yworks.com/products/yguard)
3. Unpack the yGuard archive and navigate to the `doc` directory.
4. There is an html "how to" file. Read up on that, and you should be ready to release minified code.
5. Optional: search the net for yGuard tips & tricks to get the most out of your builds.

--- WORKING-NOTES ---

[1.0] In IntelliJ 2017, there is an option to generate the Ant Build File on the build menu. `Build->Generate Ant Build File` The settings that work for me are single-build-file, with everything else checked, using the supplied project name.

[1.1] `View->Tool Windows->Ant Build` this should get you where you need to be with the knowledge you got from the [5th step](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/adding-build-file-to-project.html)  of the link at step `1` and step `4` of this answer.

Here is my working yGuard task:

```
<target depends="artifact.project" name="yguard">
<taskdef name="yguard"
         classname="com.yworks.yguard.YGuardTask"
         classpath="yguard.jar"/>
<yguard>

  <inoutpair in="${temp.jar.path.project.jar}"
             out="${artifact.output.project}/project-release.jar"/>

    <shrink
            logfile="shrinklog.xml">
        <keep>
            <class classes="protected"
                   methods="protected"
                   fields="protected"/>
        </keep>
    </shrink>

</yguard>
```

Then you modify your "all" to look like this:

```
  <target name="all" depends="build.modules, build.all.artifacts, yguard"
          description="build all">
      <!-- Delete temporary files -->
      <delete dir="${artifacts.temp.dir}"/>

  </target>
```

And you have to REMOVE the `delete temporary files` action from the `build.all.artifacts` target, so when you get to the `all` target, the files are still available.

Just like it says in the yGuard `html doc` at the bottom, IntelliJ will complain about your yGuard syntax, but yGuard will still work.

If anyone can clean this up, feel free. It works for me, your mileage may vary. Also, you WILL be able to create a really tiny ant build xml, and use the `Project Structure->Artifacts->Post Processing`, after you have added your "tiny" ant build as noted in `WORKING-NOTES: [1.1] "5th step"`. Some hand-hacking will definitely be required for this.

Comment: This definitely works. The syntax is really wierd, but once you get the hang of it, it is absolutely brilliant. I recommend that, you use the post-processing method, with a build file that contains NOTHING BUT your yguard stuff between the project tags. The default generator doesn't jive well with standard IntelliJ projects. The generator didn't even include my manifest. Also, you can use raw strings instead of variables in the build file, or you can set your variables from the post-processing dialog. If you are using much reflection, you will need to work on your selective targeting; Cheers.

Comment: Standard pro-guard click-n-go configurations have "NOTHING" on this baby! You will need this plugin to help you with debugging your setup: [Archive Browser](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9491-archive-browser). The plugin let's you browse the jar file, so you can see what other people will see when they decompile; then you can go back to your build file and nix everything that doesn't use reflection, that is also too descriptive.

Comment: Mmm Ant. 2000 called, it wants its build tools back.

Comment: unix 1970 called, said it wants real coders with the skills to get the job done.

Comment: this did not work for me !!! after running Ant Build it create a jar file without any thing and only contains a MAFIFEST.MF !!!

Comment: @M2E67 that's unfortunate. i however, did get a working system following these steps METICULOUSLY. Nothing mentioned in the writeup is optional. You must also comprehend the build tools you are using. MILEAGE WILL VARY.

Comment: if you don't know how to manage the project build process, start with an empty project, so you don't have to mess with any production code while you learn the tool-kit/ide build system. start breaking things, and inspecting them. you will get there if you want to.

Comment: either you wiped your files, or you did not use the ide: `Project Structure->Artifacts->Post Processing`. best guess for @M2E67. You might practice using the ant build targets only to test your configuration sanity. ant has it's own build window by the way...

Answer (score 4):

**1.** add plugin Intellijguar2

[image]

**2.** in **Project Structure ->modules->obfuscation** press download **yguard** as it prompts. It brings to a html page where yguard is placed next to right edge of the page. Unzip.Get jar. Navigate to the jar. Set its path. Uncheck **pedantic error-checking** (optionally) , define project's MainClass. Ok it.

**3.** Build **->** Build project **->** build artifacts and get ordinary executable  jar.
(If you cannot  see artifacts enabled in Run menu go to file-> project structure ->artfact and create by + new item with dependensy to the main class)

**4.** build **->** obfuscate *** module

[image]

**5.** Add `YourProject/out/production/YourProject/firstfolder_of_packagename`  containing your project's ***.class** files(mine was 'uz', e.g.) .

**6.** Remove **Module compile output**   Assign a path to the  jar to be obfuscated below and press 'build'

**7.** Open obfuscated jar with zip program. Make sure the class files are all obfuscated by JD-GUI app.

**8.**  cut off META-INF folder and add META-INF one from executable inobfuscated jar and also  folders like libs  or assets(or find out them in artifacts you setup previously) manually.
In turn you'll get an obfuscated executable jar
E.g. for json lib finally I've got  the result view in zip editor:
[image]

Comment: followed your steps as much as I could.. I'm stuck. The option to obfuscate (under Build is disabled)

Comment: @pulancheck1988 , you mean wasnt obfuscated or you couldnt see whether it got obfuscated?